# How to execute and fetch query created from \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder

Tags: phalcon

Hey I wanna fetch this query but cant find result from google or stackoverflow

my code is like:

```
         $params = array(
        'models'     => array('hits'),
        'columns'    => array('icerik', 'COUNT(*)'),
        'conditions' => array(
            array(
                "durum = 1"
            ),
        ),
        // or 'conditions' => "created > '2013-01-01' AND created < '2014-01-01'",
        'group'      => array('icerik'),
        'order'      => array('COUNT(*)'),
        'limit'      => 20,
        // or 'limit' => array(20, 20),
    );
    $queryBuilder = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder($params);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You would do something along the lines of

```
$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

to get the result set.